# How do i convert the following recursive dp to iterative

Tags: python, recursion, dynamic-programming

I'm trying to convert the following recursive code to bottom up/iterative Dynamic Programming.
However I cannot figure out the order in which I should iterate as the states depend on next and previous index.

```
matrix = [[-1, 4, 5, 1],
      [ 2,-1, 2, 4],
      [ 3, 3,-1, 3],
      [ 4, 2, 1, 2]]
rows = len(matrix)
cols = len(matrix[0])
cache = {}

def maxsum(dir, x, y):
   key = (dir, x, y)
   if key in cache: return cache[key]
   base = matrix[y][x]
   if x < cols-1:
       best = base + maxsum(2, x+1, y)
   else:
       best = base
   if dir != 0 and y > 0:
       best = max(best, base + maxsum(1, x, y-1))
   if dir != 1 and y < rows-1:
       best = max(best, base + maxsum(0, x, y+1))
   cache[key] = best
   return best
```

Is it possible to convert this code to iterative?
If yes, help me out with the ordering for iterations.

'dir' can take value from 0-2.

x and y will be between 1 and 1000.

I don't want to use stack to solve this. I want to solve this using general iterative loops like the way we do in bottom up dynamic programming.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Way to go from recursion to iteration](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/159590/way-to-go-from-recursion-to-iteration)

Comment: I believe that you can solve this by making multiple passes on each column, right to left.  The first pass is to set the "base" value from the column to the right. This is followed by **rows-1** passes to propagate any superior values from one end of the column to the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general idea is to imagine the recursive call graph/tree and what the leaf nodes are; then, the iterative solution is simply going from the leaf nodes and iteratively build the tree, all the way to the root.

Of course, this is easier said than done, but often there is structure to the problem that can help in your intuition. In this particular case, this is the 2D grid.

## Intuition

Let's start by building some intuition. Look at the branches in the code. They decide whether you recurse in a particular circumstance. What do they correspond to? **When do you not recurse?** In order, these are:

- the right edge of the grid
- the top edge of the grid
- the bottom edge of the grid

We need to build these first.

## Base Case

Ask yourself: **in what circumstances do we not recurse at all**? This is the base case. In no particular order, these are:

- the top-right corner of the grid, and `dir=1`
- the bottom-right corner of the grid, and `dir=0`

## Recursive Cases

Finally, ask yourself: **starting with the values that we have, what can we calculate?**

- for the top-right corner, we can calculate the entire right edge for `dir=1`
- for the bottom-right corner, we can calculate the entire right edge for `dir=0`

From this, we can then calculate the entire right edge for `dir=2`.

Now that we've filled the values for the right edge, what can we then calculate? Remember the special circumstances above. The cells that *only* depend on the right edge are the two cells in the top and bottom edges immediately to the left of the right edge, with `dir=1` and `dir=0`, respectively.

With that in hand, we can now calculate the second column from the right for `dir=1` and `dir=0`, and therefore `dir=2`.

Repeat until you find the value for the cell you wanted.

## The Code

Note: this is a little suboptimal because it fills the entire table, but it should suffice to illustrate the idea.

```
def fill(dir, x, y):
    base = matrix[y][x]
    if x < cols-1:
        best = base + cache[2, x + 1, y]
    else:
        best = base
    if dir != 0 and y > 0:
        best = max(best, base + cache[1, x, y - 1])
    if dir != 1 and y < rows - 1:
        best = max(best, base + cache[0, x, y + 1])
    cache[dir, x, y] = best


def maxsum(dir, x, y):
    for i in range(cols - 1, -1, -1):
        for j in range(rows - 1, -1, -1):
            fill(0, i, j)
        for j in range(rows):
            fill(1, i, j)
        for j in range(rows):
            fill(2, i, j)
    return cache[dir, x, y]
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thanks.